# Solution: Mulesoft, Anypoint studio WSDL Connector There has been an error retrieving the following wsdl resource

Tags: wsdl, anypoint-studio, connector

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: There has been an error retrieving the following wsdl resource

Answer (score 0):

If anyone out there getting this error then simply just upgrade your runtime version to 3.9.1